# How to use an Ł with the complexity package

Tags: fonts

The complexity package redefines \L so you don't get an L with a stroke through it (that is Ł). How can you still get that Polish letter when using the package? Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bold,basic]{complexity}

\begin{document}
Even Ł gets rendered as a bold L.
\begin{thebibliography}{50}
\bibitem{GKKLS:2015} Homer J.  {\L}{\k{a}}cki. \textsl{Mmmmm...donuts}.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

I particularly want to use it in the bibliography.

Comment: Don't use `complexity`, that's all. Really, if a package does something like this, it goes against all basic LaTeX conventions.

Comment: You state that you use utf8 in your preamble - why don't you just type the Ł?

Comment: @nhck I added an example to the question. Even if you add Ł you get a bold L when using the complexity package.

Comment: @Lembik The package has been updated! `:-D` Add the `disableredefinitions` option and it's all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package has

```
% We redefine 4 commands inside of Latex, but preserve them for usage

\let\defaultL\L
\renewcommand{\L}{\ComplexityFont{L}}
\let\defaultP\P
\renewcommand{\P}{\ComplexityFont{P}}
\let\defaultS\S
\renewcommand{\S}{\ComplexityFont{S}}
```

This goes against all basic LaTeX conventions of *not redefining* macros that pertain to the LaTeX internal character representation (LICR). There should at least be an option for not redefining `\L`, `\P` and `\S`.

The workaround of using `\defaultL`, `\defaultP` and `\defaultS` mentioned in the manual is ineffective, because if one types `Ł`, `¶` or `§` using UTF-8, the result will be **L**, **P** and **S** respectively, because the UTF-8 characters are translated back in the LICR to `\L`, `\P` and `\S`. There should be, at least, an option for avoiding those redefinitions.

However, it's easy to go back:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bold,basic]{complexity}

% fix the bad mistake in complexity.sty
\let\L\defaultL
\let\P\defaultP
\let\S\defaultS

\begin{document}
Even Ł gets rendered as a bold L.
\begin{thebibliography}{50}
\bibitem{GKKLS:2015} Homer J.  {\L}{\k{a}}cki. \textsl{Mmmmm...donuts}.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## UPDATE

As of version 0.81a of the `complexity` package, released 2017-09-16, the `disableredefinitions` option is available. With the option, `\L`, `\P` and `\S` are not redefined and instead `\cL`, `\cP` and `\cS` can be used as shorthands for `\ComplexityFont{L}`, `\ComplexityFont{P}` and `\ComplexityFont{P}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bold,basic,disableredefinitions]{complexity}

\begin{document}
Now Ł gets rendered correctly and \cL{} prints the class

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{GKKLS:2015} Homer J.  {\L}{\k{a}}cki. \textsl{Mmmmm...donuts}.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How does it manage to stop Ł being rendered correctly?

Comment: @Lembik The package redefines `\L` and the UTF-8 character `Ł` is internally translated into `\L` again.

Comment: I filed a bug report to the package author

Answer (score 1):

This is from the package documentation

> Three  commands  in  the
>   complexity
>   package  override  built-in  T
>   E
>   X  commands.
>   Specifically,
>   \L
>   (which typesets the symbol  L),
>   \P
>   (typesetting
>   ¶
>   ), and
>   \S
>   (which
>   typesets the symbol
>   §
>   ) are all redefined for use in the package.  The
>   complexity
>   package preserves these commands so that you may still use them.  To use any of
>   these symbols, use the commands
>   **\defaultL**
>   ,
>   \defaultP
>   , and
>   \defaultS
>   instead

Comment: This workaround is useless, I'm afraid, because typing `Ł` will print a boldface L anyhow. Similarly when one types `¶` or `§`. The package author should have thought better.